# Detecting when Facebox is closed

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I need to trigger a new facebox when the old one is closed.

This is the way I am doing it now, but I feel there can be a more elegant way.

> function process(){
>
> ```
> step1(step2);
>
> //triggers the first facebox
> function step1(cb){
>   $.facebox(1);
>   $("#facebox .finished").click(function(event){
>     cb();
>   });
> };
>
> function step2(){
>   $.facebox(2);
> }   }
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', cb);
```

Or, you can emit your own custom event.

Comment: $(document).bind('close.facebox', function(){alert("ss")});

slight modification - i changed it to close, as opposed to afterClose, and it works! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this too. $(document).bind('close.facebox', function(){alert("ss")}); works great.